# What are the Binomial Theorem and General Leibniz rule special cases of?

Tags: category-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm sure it's clear to most people that there is a connection between the Binomial Theorem and General Leibniz rule, especially when seeing them side by side:
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k}\longleftrightarrow (f(x)g(x))^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} f^{(k)}(x) g^{(n-k)}(x),$$

It's been discussed here before: [Why General Leibniz rule and Newton's Binomial are so similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194948/why-general-leibniz-rule-and-newtons-binomial-are-so-similar)

There, the top answer gives a good example in terms of operators acting on polynomials, but I'd like to get even deeper and more general. I'm sure there's even more examples, which maybe the comments can add, as it would be nice to compile a list.

But in particular, can these be explained from a category-theoretic level? I.e; under what conditions and relationships between some (functors?) $\phi, \psi, \gamma$ obey the most general property that

$$\psi(\phi(X,Y),n)\cong\underset{0\leq k \leq n}{\gamma}\Bigg({n\choose k}, \psi(X, k), \psi(Y, n-k)\Bigg)$$

I.e; in the case of the binomial theorem, we have
$$\psi(x, n)=x^n, \phi(a, b)=a+b, \underset{0\leq k \leq n}{\gamma}(x_0, x_1, \cdots) = \sum_{0\leq k \leq n}(x_0 \cdot x_1 \cdots),$$
and in the case of the General Liebniz rule,
$$\psi(f, n)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f, \phi(a, b)=ab, \underset{0\leq k \leq n}{\gamma}(x_0, x_1, \cdots) = \sum_{0\leq k \leq n}(x_0 \cdot x_1 \cdots).$$

clearly there is some natural transformation between the various places that this "form" arises.

In other words,

> Is there some notion of a master theorem in which generalize the Binomial Theorem and General Leibniz rule in more abstract terms?

Comment: In your linked question, I think ziggurism's answer is the only correct answer. The other three are not, as they all resort to discussions of polynomials and power series. Yet, [an everywhere differentiable functions can be nowhere analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620290). I think these three answers are missing the point.

Comment: Category theory is not the only tool for abstraction in mathematics. This is plain algebra.

Comment: @ZhenLin This is true, though I would prefer to generalize beyond even the algebra. But given that the binomial coefficients seem fundamental to this, that may be a hard ask.

Comment: What an insane coincidence. Funny enough, I posted the question you quoted on reddit once, and then the answer by ziggurism followed by that.